# RunTime error with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to add a UIImageView object to a UIScrollView.

```
FVImageSequence *imageSquence;
[imageSquence setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
[scroll addSubview:imageSquence];
scroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

The imageSequence is an object of FVImageSequence class which inherits UIImageView

```
@interface FVImageSequence : UIImageView {
NSString *prefix;
int numberOfImages;
int current;
int previous;
NSString *extension;
int increment;
}
```

But when i run the code it is crashing.When i used a direct UIImageView object,it works fine.How can i fix this?

```
UIImageView *imageSquence;
[imageSquence setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
[scroll addSubview:imageSquence];
scroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

This code runs fine.What is the problem with the first one?

Comment: Where did you intialize UIImageView object?

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "FVImageSequence.h"
    interface CarViewController : UIViewController
    {
      IBOutlet FVImageSequence *imageSquence;
      IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
      IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
    }
    end

Comment: I have added the object in the view controller header file and accessing that object

Comment: Then use that object only, which is connected via `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre  yeah,thats what i am doing.Can you please look the further code i added in answers

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate(alloc init) a `FVImageSequence` object before using it

Comment: Really? It's not possible, you will not see that `imageView` because it's `nil`

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FVImageSequence.h"
interface CarViewViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet FVImageSequence *imageSquence;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
    }
end

Comment: This is my view controller header file and i am using the global object

Answer (score 0):

Initialize imageSquence

```
FVImageSequence *imageSquence = [[FVImageSequence alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
FVImageSequence *imageSquence = [[FVImageSequence alloc] init];//must initialize FVImageSequence class
[imageSquence setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
[scroll addSubview:imageSquence];
scroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FVImageSequence.h"
@interface CarViewViewController : UIViewController
{
 IBOutlet FVImageSequence *imageSquence;
 IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
}
@end



@implementation CarViewViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [imageSquence setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
   [scroll addSubview:imageSquence];
   scroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
}
```

here this works

```
   [imageSquence setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
   [scroll addSubview:imageSquence];
```

and this crashes

```
 [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"car_0.jpg"]];
   [scroll addSubview:img];
```

Comment: Check your IBOutlet is connected accuratly with repective object? What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Thanks it now works fine.I think something was wrong with StoryBoard connections.